Setting Country Picklist Values in Scratch Org Creation
I am making scratch orgs from an org shape that has StateAndCountryPicklist enabled. In the production org we have only United States with the 50 states enabled. Whenever we make a new scratch org with this org shape, StateAndCountryPicklist is enabled, but all countries are active and visible.
When we try to deploy an Address.settings-meta.xml file with all countries and mark them as inactive, we get an error Cannot make country Andorra inactive after State and Country/Territory Picklists has been enabled. If we try to deploy an Address.settings-meta.xml file similar to the example here, then all countries remain active.
We need to have the countries be inactive and not just invisible or some of our unit tests will continue to fail. Also, we create scratch orgs in a GitLab pipeline to run tests, so we need to be able to do this all in an automated way, with no manual steps.
It seems like the org shape only captures whether the picklist is enabled or disabled, and not our production settings, but then we cannot deploy our production settings while the feature is enabled. How can we create a scratch org with the same State and Country picklist settings as our production org?
